# Making a cross domain iframe interact with drag event

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I understand the problems associated with cross domain iframes but I still need a solution.

The closest I have come is hovering a `position:absolute;` element over the top of the iframe, this will still recognize my swipe or drag events. But I still need to be able to interact with the iframe underneath, as it's a commenting system.

Setting the absolute positioned element with the css property of `pointer-events:none;` enables me to interact with the comment system, but then I cannot capture the drag event.

Is there a way I can capture a drag event and still use 'pointer-events:none;`?

Comment: ahh, @charlietfl you like to rain on my parade don't you :D

Comment: Blergh, I give up. Looks like I'm going to put a fixed toggle button. Oh the humanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 has a feature to be able to send messages between top document and I frames.
http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/

Comment: This looks interesting as long as I can work out what it means and how to implement with a drag event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the contents an iframe in several situations, usually including if that iframe content comes from another domain.

I believe you can still bind events to the iframe element itself (just not the stuff inside):

```
$('iframe').on('click',function() {
    $(this).css({
        'border':'5px solid red'
    })
});
```